# Is it possible to write plugins for KeystoneJS?

Tags: plugins, keystonejs

I'm on a project where we are thinking of using KeystoneJS for our CMS.  One of the points I've been tasked with answering is whether KeystoneJS allows one to write custom plugins. I've googled and can't seem to find an answer, which would indicate that perhaps there is no way to do so.

I see that KeystoneJS has two plugins listed in their documentation, but I'm unclear whether they have a way for us to write our own.

Any info, or links to documentation or examples, would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

KeystoneJs has only list plugins support which you saw on documentation page

`atTracking` and `byTracking`.

at this time these only support to extend the list config before creating the list object internally. List plugins can be used to have reusable template fields and validation logic

above two plugin only adds two fields each. `atTracking` adds fields for tracking created and updated timestamp whereas `byTracking` adds user info for creation and updation of item.

keystone passes on full list of createlist listconfig parameter to the plugin, this plugin must return the full config for keystone to continue creating list.

EDIT

I found some examples which cane be used, will be adding to keystonejs-contrib packages.

**IpTracking** plugin which adds ip of person creating or updating the list - 
https://github.com/MadeByMike/keystone-ip-tracking-plugin/blob/master/index.js

Access Control plugin, which helps define roles based access control 
 - https://github.com/MadeByMike/keystone-access-control-demo/blob/master/plugin-access-control.js

both are made by core team member Mike Riethmuller - https://github.com/MadeByMike